# Flutter Design Pattern: Mixing build method and async function

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have the following async function that I need to call from my page build(), to get the UID of the current user. However, build() is NOT an async function, and I can't use await feature.

So what is the normal practice here?

```
Future<String> getUID() async{
  bool isLoggedInFlag = isLoggedIn();
  if (isLoggedInFlag) {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    String uid = user.uid;
    return uid
  }else{
    print("no uid found");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can call your function in the `initState()` method and store you UID in a class variable or use a `FutureBuilder` to deal with your Future function

Comment: @FPerroch I tried initState(), but It's a NOT a sync method, I can't do it. Can you show an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call an async method from initState() method but the uid will return null until the async method is finished :

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  String uid;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUID();
  }

  void getUID() async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); //Simulate the Firebase call
    setState(() {
      uid = 'firebasevalue';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(uid ?? 'loading'),
    );
  }
}
```

But it's not the only solution. You can use a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder to deal with your Futures